# How to position and resize button in telegram using telethon

Tags: python, button, telethon

I want to create Menu Buttons stacked on top of one another & long enough to accommodate the menu options in telegram chat.

Following Telethon guide [here](https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/examples/telegram-client.html#sending-messages-with-buttons), `Button.inline` creates buttons close to one another in a line. I could not find any [option](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#module-telethon.tl.custom.button) to change the button position (to make button grid of like 1x10 for menu or 2x5 etc.) and also button does not resize itself to accommodate the text.

Are button positioning and resizing possible with telethon ? If so, How can it be done ?

Comment: The API does not support resizing or positioning inline buttons in any other way than the default. The closest you can get is adding "empty" buttons that don't do anything but fill space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this. It works for me.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, Button, events 


client = TelegramClient("session", api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="/options"))
async def handler(event):

    keyboard = [
        [  
            Button.inline("First option", b"1"), 
            Button.inline("Second option", b"2")
        ],
        [
            Button.inline("Third option", b"3"), 
            Button.inline("Fourth option", b"4")
        ],
        [
            Button.inline("Fifth option", b"5")
        ]
    ]

    await client.send_message(event.chat_id, "Choose an option:", buttons=keyboard)
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: That's amazing!  Thanks a lot. Just one more, I want to create an Interactive Menu just like  [https://telegram.me/BotFather]@BotFather. On querying about bots, it displays Button Menu just like yours. Then after selecting a button, the menu quickly transforms into another Menu (during which I think old menu gets deleted/cleared and new button menu is presented). After trying your code, I added `await client.send_message(event.chat_id, 'Bye Keyboard!', buttons=Button.clear())`, but nothing happended, just "Bye Keyboard!' message was displayed.  Could you guide me ?

Comment: I was finally able to make an Interactive Menu using `await client.edit_message(event.chat_id, msg.id, "Choose an option from New Menu:",  buttons=newmenu)` where  `msg.id` is the id of previous message `msg`.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you.